# Jquery Datatable inline edit only specified column

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Currently i am using `data table` js for inline editing and it's work perfect but i would like to edit only specified column rows not all column. for example i have 4 column id,name,email,contact and i want to editable only email not all others.

i have used following script but not work.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: test,
     rowReorder: {
     dataSrc: 'order',
     selector: 'tr'
     },
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    columns: [{
      data: 'delete'
    }, {
      data: 'delete'
    }, {
      data: 'order'
    }
    , {
      data: 'agent_name', className: 'editable' 
    }

    , {
      data: 'add_mission'
    }

    , {
      data: ''
    }


    , {
      data: 'phone_number'
    }

    , {
      data: ''
    }

    , {
      data: false
    }
    ]
  });
```

On this i only allow to agent_name column should be editable not all

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which columns can be editable. By providing the td child. Here is an example code for providing editing to only td 7th child.

```
$('#table').on( 'click', 'tbody td:nth-child(7)', function (e) {
       editor.inline( this );
} );
```

Comment: I tried but still enable to edit all when i click on edit